# Как проверить тип значения при конвертации timestamp в дату

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, обработка-данных, timestamp

Конвертирую `timestamp` в `date`, как оказалось во frame могут попасться уже даты

Пример

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LAST_DATE': [274696742000, -1301790829000, None, -9544861678232, 8960604955000, pd.Timestamp(1990, 1, 1, 12)]})
```

Конвертирую так

```
df["LAST_DATE"] = (df["LAST_DATE"].div(1000).apply(lambda x: (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)))
```

Должно получится

```
out: [1978-09-15 08:39:02, 1928-09-30 23:26:11, nan, 1667-07-15 01:32:01.768000, 2253-12-13 16:55:55, 2017-01-01 12:00:00]
```

Знаю что есть проверка на тип `if isinstance(x, int)` но куда правильно воткнуть не понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, видимо, так, если подумать и правильно расставить условия и вычисления:

```
df["LAST_DATE"] = df["LAST_DATE"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x/1000) if isinstance(x, int) else x or pd.NA)
```

- Делим на 1000 только в случае, если попался `timestamp`, а не всё подряд
- Собственно `timestamp` определяем через `isinstance(x, int)`
- `None` обрабатываем с помощью трюка с `x or pd.NA` - правая часть выражения подставится, только если левая часть ложна, в вашем случае это будет если встретится `None`

Я тут подставил `pd.NA`, поскольку это родной `NaN` для `Pandas`, но вы можете использовать и `np.nan`, разницы особой нет на самом деле.

Вместо трюка с `or` можно было использовать ещё один *тернарный* оператор `x if x else pd.NA`, но через `or` тоже самое получается в два раза короче.